# javascript : how can i get array in different ways?

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi i have a little problem with my javascript
can i make the simple way to execute content of array with different character of word?
for example :

```
var word = new Array();
word [0] = "is";
word [1] = "am";
.
.
.
.
word [100] = "when";
```

var word should be access with 3 ways,in order to reduce process to execute arrays..

```
first : " "+ word +" ";
second : " "+ word;
third : word +" ";
```

-thank you for helping-

Comment: Are you able to explain that better?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify the question. For starters, you can't "execute" the contents of an array.

Comment: Can't understand what you need. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @OrangeDog `var a = [function() { alert('hello'); }]; a[0]()` [:D](http://jsfiddle.net/bzKqL/) (jokes aside, I am sure this isn't what the OP was chasing).

Comment: I'm guessing he's looking for `word.join(" ")` but who knows.

Comment: @alex - he isn't using an index, eg `a[0] != a`

Comment: @alex - I knew someone was going to do that, but I'm pretty sure these are just strings we have here.

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell I think you missed the joke =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are chasing (fill me in and I'll update), but I'd like to point out a far better way of filling in that array literal...

```
var word = [
   'is',
   'am'
];
```

You can see the index is calculated automatically, and you are not required to repeat the var name for each member definition.

#### Update

Maybe you want something you can call and get the next array member each time. This should do it...

```
function getNextMember(array, startIndex) {
   startIndex = startIndex || 0;

   return function() {
      startIndex++;  
      return array[startIndex];
   };
   
};

var getNextWord = getNextMember(word);

alert(getNextWord() + ' ' + getNextWord());
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa4yE/1/).

And of course, if you are feeling naughty, you could add that function to `Array`'s `prototype`.