# JQuery tooltip that supports new line

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I'm looking for a lightweight jquery plugin for displaying tooltips when the user hovers over an element. I would like the plugin to get the content from the title attribute and also it's important that I can make new lines.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually use [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).

---

You can add any html element in tipsy, so `<br/>` works.

You just need to pass the `html` option as such :

```
$('#example-html').tipsy({html: true });
```

If you don't want to use the `title` attribute to display html (it won't validate in this case), you can use the `fallback` option.

```
$('#example-fallback').tipsy({fallback: "Where's my tooltip yo'? <br/> yay !" });
```

[More options and examples on the tipsy webpage](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).

Comment: Is it really possible to add a new line using tipsy?

Comment: @Nordis : you can add any html in tipsy. So `<br/>` works. More details in my edit

Comment: The HTML code should validate perfectly if the attribute value is properly encoded… So `<div title="1&lt;br/&gt;2">` should validate *and* contain `"1<br/>2"` as the title attribute value.

Comment: @Tomalak : It should but as I didn't test it with tipsy, I won't be sure enough to tell it as an answer. If it works, good, else, I gave an alternative :)

Answer (score 16):

In jQuery 1.9 (jquery + jquery-ui) and standard toolTip function use this:

```
$(".myClass").tooltip({
    content: function() {
        return $(this).attr('title');
    }
})
```

And then in the title you can use HTML's 
 or .

Example:

```
<span class="myClass" title="Line1 <br> Line 2 <br> <b>Bold</b><br>">(?)</span>
```

Comment: Sadly `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'` and nothing about tootip method in jquery doc.

Comment: @Ajax do you have jquery and jquery-ui attached in your source? Tooltip class is as I remember in jquery-ui (http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: No, I know, that this is jQuery UI function, but in you post is no word about jQuery UI :)

Comment: @adek You're a genius - don't understand why/how that works but works fine.

Answer (score 9):

This code makes br in title-tag work!

```
$(document).tooltip({
    content: function() {
        var element = $(this);
        return element.attr("title");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the only answer which actually worked for me. Simple and clear!

Comment: I was looking for this answer for a long time. Worked like magic! Thanks a ton! God Bless You!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        container : 'body',
        html: true
    });
  });
});
```

After add html tag "
" inside title:

```
title=text1<br/>text2
```

Answer (score 1):

http://elliotlings.com/jquery/tooltip is a good tooltip to manage tooltips which need to hold more content

Comment: I need the plugin to get the content from the title attribute.. Thx anyway.

Comment: its easy to implement, just add "content = $(this).attr('title');" inside the jquery.tooltip file above Bounce Settings :)

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers (not Firefox or Opera - [newlines will disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491313/javascript-how-can-i-get-array-in-different-ways/4491351#4491351)) support newlines in the `title` attribute.

If your plugin doesn't render them as `<br />`, do this on the text first...

```
var tooltip = $('#whatever').attr('title').replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

... and then pass `tooltip` to your tooltip library (e.g. [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)).

Comment: I can't see that qTip supports html or new lines in tooltip. I've been looking at all the examples and none is using multiline.

Answer (score 0):

Simple custom jQuery extension:

```
$.fn.extend({
  myToolTip: function() {
    this.hover(
      // mouse in ...
      function () { 
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.attr("title")) {
          $this.data("$tooltip", $("<div class='myToolTip'></div>")
            .text($this.attr("title"))
            .html(function(i, html) { return html.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"); })
            .css({
              position: "absolute", 
              top: $this.position().top + $this.outerHeight(), 
              left: $this.position().left
            })
            .appendTo("body")
          );
        }
      },
      // mouse out ...
      function () {
        var $tooltip = $(this).data("$tooltip");
        if ($tooltip) $tooltip.remove();
      }
    );
  }
});
```

This creates a `<div class="myToolTip">` (use CSS to style it) and positions it beneath the element in question on *mouseenter*. On *mouseleave* the tooltip is removed again. Line breaks in the element's `title` will become `<br>` in the `<div>`'s contents, everything else will appear verbatim.

Call the extension via `$(".someElements").myToolTip();`.