# pull name attribute out of nested User array ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

```
board.voters_who_voted
```

returns an array containing rows from the User table. The attribute I want to pull out is the name.

Example output (only one user here):

```
[#<User id: 71, name: "montgomery Thamavaranacupt", email: "jmash@aol.com", created_at: "2013-01-27 05:32:30", updated_at: "2013-04-24 07:07:43", password_digest: "$2a$10$Es/olEq0.w6vcnn4.8v0.O0VXDP1c7nktcW85UFtG91e...", remember_token: "ttPm1aTE6WBm3WVx4EJTew", admin: false, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, avatar: 0>]
```

I suppose I need to iterate through the entire array and print the names.

This is what I tried:

```
board.voters_who_voted.each {|x| puts x.name}
```

however this just returns the entire array for some reason

```
board.voters_who_voted[0].name
```

the above properly returns the name of the first user but i need this for all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
board.voters_who_voted.map(&:name)
```

Since you want to use this in the title attribute, I recommend the following:

```
<%= link_to .., .., :title => board.voters_who_voted.map(&:name).join("\n").html_safe %>
```

Comment: This works, thanks! quick search indicates map and collect work the same way

Comment: @ayounesi, yeah they are actually aliases of each other.

Comment: I'm actually doing this for a tooltip so it's in the title element of a link_to. Not sure how to put the <br/> tag within the quotes title: "#{board.voters_who_voted.collect(&:name).join("\n")}" what i had. \n still does nothing

Comment: still no dice but Ill tinker with it some more

Comment: @ayounesi What's the problem with this code then? Why doesn't it work? Any errors? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: just not line breaking between names

Comment: @ayounesi If this doesn't work your browser doesn't support line breaks in tooltips. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip).

Comment: My problem may have been unique to my tooltip tipsy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491446/jquery-tooltip-that-supports-new-line